# query SSAS to find if table is used in cubes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx, dmx-ssas

I have an SSAS instance with a number of databases containing cubes. I need to check if given tables/dimensions are used in the cubes.Maybe this could do the job

```
SELECT [CATALOG_NAME] as [DATABASE],
CUBE_NAME AS [CUBE],DIMENSION_CAPTION AS [DIMENSION]
 FROM $system.MDSchema_Dimensions
WHERE CUBE_NAME  ='Adventure Works'
AND DIMENSION_CAPTION <> 'Measures'
ORDER BY DIMENSION_CAPTION
```

but how do i modify ti to run for all the databases in the instance (and all the cubes in each db)?

Comment: it is not the case just to remove CUBE_NAME  ='Adventure Works' in where clause   ?